# Converting ADC 16 bit quantity back to original input?

Tags: binary, formula, bit, adc

So I have an adc converts an analog signal into an unsigned 16 bit quantity, how would I be able to convert this 16 bit value back to the original input?

For example I have an input voltage between -5v and 5v thats being converted into a 16bit unsigned quantity I'm trying to setup a formula to convert it back to the original value.

So here I'd just have a range of 10v, from what i can tell I would just convert the 16 bit value to decimal and subtract half of the range to get the original value no?

so my equation would be something like

```
original value = [(digital value * 10) / 2^16] - 5
```

where 10 is the range of voltage, 2^16 is my number of digital codes, and -5 is my offset, but this seems too simple and I'm nearly positive it isn't correct, is this the way adc's work?

I've been referencing this powerpoint which I found on google

```
http://class.ece.iastate.edu/arun/Cpre381_Sp06/lectures/adc.ppt
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which ADC are you using refer to it's manual it will have details.
Are you sure that it is giving unsigned 16 bit out? can you check in the data sheet about this?
Also I would suggest take the 16 bits and print them on terminal if you have some serial uart or something then you can see. That's the way I determined the exact output format of my ADC.
Sometimes you have to change the multiplier that (*10 or 5) depending on what the ADC output is but this thing can only be get cleared after looking the datasheet.
In General case your formula is correct.